# C#: Is there a way to properly convert Keys.Oem? to proper string without doing string manipulation?

Tags: c#, .net

C#: Is there a method to convert Keys.Oem? to proper string without doing string manipulation?

When I do e.ToString() and if the key is a / or <, and so on, it converts as OemSlash, OemQuestion. Is there a way .net method properly convert Keys.OemSpace to "Space" without it including "OemSpace" and without string manipulation? And if there's not a built-in method to do such a thing, what would be the best way to go upon it then?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to determine what character you will get from a given key with given modifiers, you should use the [`user32 ToAscii`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646316.aspx) function. Or [`ToAsciiEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646318.aspx) if you want to use a keyboard layout *other* then the current one.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public static class User32Interop
{
  public static char ToAscii(Keys key, Keys modifiers)
  {
    var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder(2);
    int result = ToAscii((uint)key, 0, GetKeyState(modifiers),
                         outputBuilder, 0);
    if (result == 1)
      return outputBuilder[0];
    else
      throw new Exception("Invalid key");
  }

  private const byte HighBit = 0x80;
  private static byte[] GetKeyState(Keys modifiers)
  {
    var keyState = new byte[256];
    foreach (Keys key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
    {
      if ((modifiers & key) == key)
      {
        keyState[(int)key] = HighBit;
      }
    }
    return keyState;
  }

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern int ToAscii(uint uVirtKey, uint uScanCode,
                                    byte[] lpKeyState,
                                    [Out] StringBuilder lpChar,
                                    uint uFlags);
}
```

You can now use it like this:

```
char c = User32Interop.ToAscii(Keys.OemQuestion, Keys.ShiftKey); // = '?'
```

If you need more than one modifier, just `or` them. `Keys.ShiftKey | Keys.AltKey`

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do this is to use regular expressions. I know this isn't the answer you probably wanted. Hopefully someone knows of a method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [`ToAscii`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ToAscii.html) or [`ToUnicode`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ToUnicode.html) function for this, which is part of the Win32 API. (I doubt you're going to get a simple pure BCL/cross-platform solution, if that's what you want.) They're relatively simple functions that convert virtual key codes to characters (either in ASCII or Unicode encoding, as the names suggest).

**Edit:** I think you may actually be in luck with the [`KeysConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keysconverter.aspx) class!

Comment: KeysConverter seems to be almost useless. Keys.D3 | Keys.Shift produces "Shift+3".

Comment: Yeah, so that's not what is needed. I'll remove that and leave the original part of the post.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the answer from [Samuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32465/samuel), to get rid of the modifiers key.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class ConvertKey
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ToAscii(int VirtualKey, int ScanCode, byte[] lpKeyState, ref uint lpChar, int uFlags);

        public static char GetChar(Keys key, bool shift)
        {
            uint lpChar = 0;
            byte[] lpKeyState = new byte[256];
            if (shift)
            {
                var mKey = Keys.ShiftKey;
                foreach (Keys sKey in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
                    if ((mKey & sKey) == sKey)
                        lpKeyState[(int)sKey] = 0x80;
            }
            ToAscii((int)key, 0, lpKeyState, ref lpChar, 0);
            return (char)lpChar;
        }
    }
```